# for every new post on Facebook page send broadcast

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot

I am creating a chatbot and I am doing it well. But now I am having one question about Facebook Broadcasting API and Graph API.

I am asking subscription for the page through the messenger Chatbot, if a user subscribes it, Now whenever I post something on My facebook page I want to send that post as a message to all subscribed users.

is there anyone who tried it before is it possible? 
I am not using any third party like chatfuel or manychat (i am doing everything with Coding in Node.js)

Comment: I very much doubt Facebook would classify that as one of the allowed use cases in the first place. People can follow your page already to get notifications when you post something new via the existing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Whether this would be allowed would entirely depend on the content of the broadcast. If it is non promotional and falls in one of the allowed use cases for promotional messaging, then yes, you could do this with the Broadcast API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy/policy-overview#subscription_messaging